# Transfer Hook: Not backwards compatible with common wallets

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program, token-2022

As far as I understand from documentation all the Token-2022 extensions should be backwards compatible with normal transfers from spl-token standard. However when testing Transfer Hooks I was only able to create the token untransferable by common wallets (I tried Phantom, Solflare, Backpack) but the token was transferable by CLI.

When trying to transfer with wallet I get the error message `Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x7dc8348c` which translates to `Incorrect account provided` error. This does not happen if I create ATA account prior to transfer and initiate transfer with CLI.

My guess is that CLI transfer uses `TransferChecked` function and fetches / appends `ExtraAccoountMetaList` accounts automatically while wallets do not have this functionality, failing to append meta accounts resulting in wrong payload.

In my case I did not even need meta accounts at all but it looks like transaction needs at least *some* data to succeed, even if they are blank data.

I tried to ditch all the meta-related code from example program I deployed but had no luck with bypassing this functionality. Maybe I am just missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've noticed the problem perfectly -- the normal instruction creators will not check for a transfer hook and add the required accounts. The CLI does all of this for you through the `spl-token-client` crate in Rust.

In JS, you can use the `createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction` helper at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/5a1a2b2a8010b3e34fa6ef70b4ae15aebbd3ceb6/token/js/src/extensions/transferHook/instructions.ts#L317C23-L317C71

It takes all of the same parameters as normal `transferChecked` instruction:

```
let instruction = await createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction(
    connection,
    source,
    mint,
    destination,
    owner,
    amount,
    decimals
);
```

Eventually, all wallets and dapps need to switch to using this creator if they want to support mints with a transfer hook

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I noticed there is also createTransferCheckedWithFeeAndTransferHookInstruction in the ts file you provided. I needed both fees and transfer hooks in my token. I think it will be impossible for dapp to know which function to use even in the future. For now those tokens are unusable in a state like that - untransferrable, untradable. I hope they learn in Solana to do things properly in the future.

Comment: You don't need to use `transferCheckedWithFeeAndTransferHookInstruction` if your token has a transfer fee. The `WithFee` part just allows you to specify the expected fee to be paid so you don't get rugged. A normal `transferChecked` works just fine otherwise.